# Why won't any jquery work in IE9?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, cufon

http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/class/wordpress/

Everything on this project is done except getting it to work in IE9 and I can't figure out what is causing jquery to break.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have a conditional block which runs this javascript

```
Cufon.set('engine', 'canvas');
```

My guess is that it's trying to run before the page has loaded (and therefore the Cufon library)

Try wrapping it in a document ready block

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        Cufon.set('engine', 'canvas');
    });
</script>
```

**Edit:**

Just saw that all the other Cufon is running AFTER the cufon-yui.js file is inlcuded, whereas this is before.

Move it after `<script src="http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/class/wordpress/wp-content/themes/class/js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` this line

Answer (score 0):

I tested the IE. jQuery is available and of course, the slider of the header worked. Seems that your IE has problems.